# Just In Time controller showing User.surname and User.FirstName all null

Tags: apex, saml

I have written Just in Time (JIT) controller to handle JIT scenarios. Azure is passing the Identity provider details. But in salesforce, all values like below showing null, despite those are in the SAML request received.

```
     attributes.containsKey('User.displayname') are null
     attributes.containsKey('User.mail') are null
```

when I printed attributes it does not have those values.

Below is part of SAML received:

```xml
<Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid">
    <AttributeValue>2bb82c64-2eb1</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier">
    <AttributeValue>085fc16b-532d-4f4</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname">
    <AttributeValue>TEST_APIPORTAL</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider">
    <AttributeValue>https://sts.windows.net/2bb82c64-2eb1-43f7-8862-fdc1d2333b50/</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences">
<AttributeValue>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
    <AttributeValue>TEST_APIPORTAL@abc.com</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
```

Below are attributes values I have printed in logs.

U`SER_DEBUG [174]|DEBUG|Printing Attributes{http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport, http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname=TEST_APIPORTAL, http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider=https://sts.windows.net/2bb82c64-2eb1-43f7-8862-abgdfdf678/, http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier=085fc16b-532d-4f4b-9ba6-ebea6b93c53fytr, http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid=2b876`

Comment: Your SAML assertion does not have `User.displayname` or `User.mail`. Take a look at [Debug & Run Diagnostics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_basics_dotnet/debugging_diagnostics) trailhead and learn how to use a debug log. Had you done so, you would have been able to send the method parameters your JIT handler received to the log and see the names of attributes.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply identigral. I am little confused in my Saml Assertion there are attributes with displayname and name for example --Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
    <AttributeValue>TEST_APIPORTAL@abc.com</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>

Comment: Where does it say `User.displayname`

Comment: Oh ok, I thought  since attribute has value Name and displayname, so I can use it. I guess I need to decode assertion passed by salesforce using Base64 decoder and then I can parse and read it. Correct? In below method for JIT handler -->  global User createUser(Id samlSsoProviderId, Id communityId, Id portalId, 
        String federationIdentifier, Map < String, String > attributes, String assertion) .. salesforce is passing assertion.

Comment: It's already parsed and decoded for you. `Map <String, String> attributes` has what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey When I printed Map of attributes,  it's not showing display name or mail of user. But as you can see it's is attributes.  Can you please tell me how can I retrieve name from this assertion. We have configured these claims in Azure which is acting as Identity provider and you see claim is getting passed also-Name="schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"> <AttributeValue>TEST_APIPORTAL@abc.com</AttributeValue> </Attribute> – But not sure how can i retreive that in my apex handler of JIT.  attributes.containsKey('User.name') are null

Comment: Please edit your post and include the debug log that shows the contents of the `attributes` map

Comment: @identigral  I have added logs of attributes.  Please see there are attributes with name displayname